# Javascript keydown function conflict on input focus

Tags: javascript

How to prevent keydown event when input is focused?

I have a function that assigns some action to keyboard keys (mainly player control), but when using `<input>` all assigned keys trigger that action as well. Therefore it is impossible to use `<input>` properly when typing.

```js
function keyboardShortcuts(e){
        
  //Do some stuff when keyboard keys are pressed
  
  switch(e.code){
  
    case 'KeyJ':
      console.log('KeyJ');
      break;
    
    //...
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',keyboardShortcuts);
```

```html
<input id="search" placeholder="search...">
```

How to fix it? Should I check if input is not focused?

```
function keyboardShortcuts(e){
    if(document.getElementById('search') !== document.activeElement){
        switch(e.code){
            //...
       }
    }
}
```

Or maybe there is some method similar to `e.preventDefault()`?

```
document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('focus',function(){
    //... prevent keyboardShortcuts frum running ?????
});
```

Comment: TBH I think this is more of a design problem. If you're just trying to make custom keyboard shortcuts on an input, think about how CTRL + V/C (copy/paste) works. I think the important thing is to make an irrelevant key (like CTRL) be the deciding factor of if a user is explicitly typing something or not. One could assume that if CTRL is being held and another key is pressed, you're trying to run a shortcut and not wanting to actually type a value in.

Comment: Jakub - I wanted to let you know I edited my answer again to provide a way to add a class to entire containers of elements. This way you don't have to keep adjusting your `keydown` code, or adding classes to each individual element. Work smarter, not harder :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Answer:

Since you're applying the `keydown` event handler to the entire document, the best way to handle this is to diffuse the function based upon what element initiated the event. You can find this out by using `event.target`

Combining this with `HTMLElement.prototype.matches` can allow you to avoid elements that match a `selector`, for instance any `input` elements.

```
  if(e.target.matches("input")) return;
```

---

### Example:

```js
function keyboardShortcuts(e){
        
  //Do some stuff when keyboard keys are pressed
  if(e.target.matches("input")) return;
  switch(e.code){
  
    case 'KeyJ':
      console.log('KeyJ');
      break;
    
    //...
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',keyboardShortcuts);
```

```html
<h3> Will Escape Custom KeyDown </h3>
<input id="search" placeholder="search...">
<hr />
<h3> Will Trigger Custom KeyDown </h3> 
<textarea></textarea>
<hr/>
  <small> Pressing <kbd>J</kbd> will fire <highlight>console.log</highlight> from Custom KeyDown Event</small>
```

You'll notice, in the above, `input` doesn't fire a console log when pressing `j`, but `textarea` still does.

---

### Adding a Class:

I would suggest adding a specific class to your markup that is used for avoiding the global `keydown` handler. For instance something like `defaultKeys`

---

### Example:

```js
function keyboardShortcuts(e){
        
  //Do some stuff when keyboard keys are pressed
  if(e.target.matches(".defaultKeys")) return;
  switch(e.code){
  
    case 'KeyJ':
      console.log('KeyJ');
      break;
    
    //...
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown',keyboardShortcuts);
```

```html
<h3> Defaulted KeyDown Events </h3>
<hr/>
<input id="search" class="defaultKeys" placeholder="search...">
<br>
<textarea class="defaultKeys"></textarea>
<hr/>
<h3> Custom KeyDown Events </h3>
<input />
<br>
<textarea></textarea>
<hr/>
<small> Pressing <kbd>J</kbd> will fire <highlight>console.log</highlight> from Custom KeyDown Event</small>
```

---

### Avoiding Groups of Elements:

It may be beneficial to avoid entire containers of elements - a.e. if you have a submission form or a player chat, etc.

You can utilize the same basic principles, but because currently `selector`s cannot look up the tree( they can't say *am I a great-grandchild of an element that **does** match `.defaultKeys` ?* ) we have to recursively check up the tree.

This is done with a simple `do...while` loop that continues until it finds a match for the specified selector OR it hits the `body` tag.

The second out( the `body` tag check ) is normally not necessary as `parentElement` should only be able to go up to the `HTML` element, however, when dealing with IFrames, DOMParser, and, in the future, **Realms** - you may have multiple DOMs injected into one another, and therefore, multiple `body` tags.

Basically, we simply want to give a for-sure recursive out when it reaches the top of the **current** DOM.

```js
function keyboardShortcuts(e) {
// get init element and set default flag
  let element = e.target,
    useDefault = false;

// if this element has defaultKeys class
// OR if any parent element has defaultKeys class
// set default flag to true

  do {
    if (element.matches(".defaultKeys")) {
      useDefault = true;
      break;
    }
    if ( element.tagName === "BODY" ) break;
  } while ((element = element.parentElement));

// if flag is true, escape function
  if (useDefault) return;

// check for custom key events
    switch (e.code) {
      case "KeyJ":
        console.log("KeyJ");
    }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyboardShortcuts);
```

```html
<div id="group" class="defaultKeys">
  <h3> These elements are in the same parent div </h3>
  <input />
  <br/>
  <textarea></textarea>
  
</div>
<h3> Outside of Group </h3>
<textarea></textarea>
```

---

### Conclusion

Hope this helps! **Happy coding!**

Comment: of course, if you have a textarea you also want to ignore this handler in, then this would need to change.

Comment: @Bravo Well, right. I edited my code to explain how to avoid that eventuality.